# Pause/Terminate Spring @Component with @Scheduled

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I have a use case where I have a class with @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000) on a method (say run()).

I want to be able to:

1. Launch new instances of this class (with singleton scope) at runtime with different bean names.
2. Selectively terminate an instance at runtime (based on bean name).
3. Pause the execution of an instance (based on bean name).
4. Resume the execution of an instance which was paused before (based on bean name).

For launching/terminating such singletons I can use BeanDefinitionRegistry's registerBeanDefinition & removeBeanDefinition methods respectively.

Questions:

1. After registerBeanDefinition, will the registered bean run the method marked with @Scheduled annotation?
2. After removeBeanDefinition, will the removed instance stop executing method marked with @Scheduled annotation?
3. What's the best way to pause & resume execution of method marked with @Scheduled annotation. I can always expose a method which sets a flag to true and busy wait to pause but is there an elegant way or some functionality provided by container I can use?

Comment: for: Question1 and Question2: what is the result of your tests -- I expect you have done some tests before asking.